# Elul's acronyms

Tags: elul, acronyms

What are the Roshei Teivos (acronyms) of Elul (א.ל.ו.ל) and what are their significances?

Comment: Curmudegeony nitpick: I'd say "What are some backronyms for Elul", or "What phrases form the acronym Elul"?  Technically, the acronym for Elul is just Aleph.

Comment: אני לאומן ואשתי לבד

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire "official" list (brought by the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch) is:

- את לבבך ואת לבב (symbolizing teshuvah) - [Devarim 30:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0530.htm#6)
- אני לדודי ודודי לי (symbolizing tefillah) - [Shir Hashirim 6:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3006.htm#3)
- איש לרעהו ומתנות לאביונים (symbolizing tzedakah) - [Ester 9:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3309.htm#22)
- אנה לידו ושמתי לך (symbolizing Torah, a "place of refuge" for us) - [Shemot 21:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0221.htm#13)

and out of order:

- 'ויאמרו לאמר אשירה לה (symbolizing the redemption) - [Shemot 15:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0215.htm#1)

Answer (score 9):

The counts are number of occurrences of the phrase in Tanach.

אחרים לעבדם ולהשתחות להם 3

איפה לפר ואיפה לאיל 2

אחד לחטאת ואחד לעלה 2

אתננה לו ותהי לו 1

אתן לזרעכם ונחלו לעלם 1

אתכם לעולם ואתם לא 1

אתכם לחרב וכלכם לטבח 1

אתך לשמה וישביה לשרקה 1

אתיכם לחרבות ומזמרתיכם לרמחים 1

אתו לאשם ואת לג 1

את למך ויקח לו 1

את לבו ויהי לעת 1

את לבו ואת לב 1

את לבבך ואת לבב 1

אשר לשאול ויאמר לאנשיו 1

אשר לפניך ואחריך לא 1

אשר לו ויקראו לפניו 1

אשר לו ויאמר לו 1

אשר לאבינו ומאשר לאבינו 1

אשה ליהוה וחטאתם לפני 1

אשה ליהוה ובעשור לחדש 1

אפוד לפני ואתנה לבית 1

אסלח לעונם ולחטאתם לא 1

אנשים לפנינו ויחפרו לנו 1

אנכי לאביונים ורב לא 1

אני לדודי ודודי לי 1

אנחנו לך ומהללים לשם 1

אנה לידו ושמתי לך 1

אמר לנער ויעבר לפנינו 1

אם לצרינו ויאמר לא 1

אללי לי וצדקתי לא 1

אלי לשרתני ועמדו לפני 1

אלהים לשלמה ויאמר לו 1

אלה לפניך ואמרת לעבדך 1

אלה ליהוה ואשה לא 1

אל לוט ויאמרו לו 1

אכל לחם ויטב לבך 1

איש לרעהו ומתנות לאבינים 1

איש לנחלתו ואיש לארצו 1

איש לאחיו ואיש לרעהו 1

איש לאהלו ואבשלם לקח 1

איד לעול ונכר לפעלי 1

אחינו לבנתיו והיו לאחד 1

אחימעץ לצדוק ויהונתן לאביתר 1

אחד לצדיק ולרשע לטוב 1

אחד לעלה ואחד לחטאת 1

אחד לכל וגם לב 1

אחד להלל ולהדות ליהוה 1

אחאב לשמרון ויזבח לו 1

אוכל לגאל וזאת לפנים 1

או לנקבה ואם לא 1

אהלים לשדדים ובטחות למרגיזי 1

אבן לפנה ואבן למוסדות 1

אבימלך לאברהם ויאמר לו 1

אבה לשלחם ויאמר לו 1

Comment: Great Stuff But you missed a part of the question:
"are their significances?"

Comment: I'm assuming you had some way of searching for this (as opposed to finding them all manually). How did you do it?

Comment: Same way I've done other counts of Gemara and the like: download the text from mechon mamre, parse it with a script.

Answer (score 5):

Ani Ldodi v'dodi Li.  Is the most common.  It is supposed to be a segula for marriages occurring during the month.  It is also supposed to be siman for the gates of Chesed being opened and repentance being accepted(taken from the Zohar Shiur for Parashat Re'eh found at HaZohar.net).  In conjunction with that the acronym is also found in the Posuk in Devarim(30:6).

Additionally it is found in the posuk of Esther 9:22 dealing with sending gifts to friends and the needy.  Though the source for part of the Purim celebration I have heard that it also serves to remind us that part of repentance is Tzedakah.

Comment: Ish lreahu Umatnos Levyonim

Comment: no one said: Oy Li Vay Li